# How to pass function and prop function to onClick?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, react-props

I'm try to add on click prop function and function on click to run on the same click. prop is function that show sorted list and useState to show which btn active. The problem is when i push a btn it doesn't sort(doesn't run prop), but prop and useState by themselfs works good.I know problem with prop syntax. I'm new in react and probably dont know needed syntax.

```
const TaskFilter = ({ showActive, showAll, showCompleted }) => {

    const [activeBtn, setActiveBtn] = useState('All')
    
    return (
    <div className="task-filter">
        <Button
            text='All'
            onClick={() => { showAll; setActiveBtn('All') }}
            activeBtn={ activeBtn} />
        <Button
            text='Active'
            onClick={() => { showActive; setActiveBtn('Active') }
            activeBtn={ activeBtn}}/>
        <Button text='Completed'
            onClick={() => { showCompleted; setActiveBtn('Completed') }}
            activeBtn={ activeBtn} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

I tried google it, checked docs, made function to handle click and add everything there,but its doesn't help

```
const handleClick = (action,id) => {
        action 
        setActiveBtn(id) 
    }
```

Comment: You have to call those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the action functions. For example:

```
onClick={() => {
  showAll();
  setActiveBtn('All'):
}}
```

Comment: is docs for this syntax or a video? thanks for hepl